# Multipart-form-data POST request for Uploading Files

Tags: multipartform-data, advanced-rest-client

While integrating FreshDesk in my product,I am stuck with Create Ticket with attachment API. I am using Advanced Rest Client for testing APIs.I have seen many forums and questions on the Stack Overflow itself but I am still not satisfied with any answer pertaining to multipart-form-data POST request for uploading files.

I would like to know the Request Format required in Advanced Rest Client along with headers.
As of now, this is the request I am using but I am not getting a proper response:

```
-----------------------------7d01ecf406a6
Content-Disposition: form-data;name="files";filename="text1.txt"
Content-Type:text/plain
Its a nice day.
-----------------------------7d01ecf406a6--
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just spent the last hour on this same issue, thinking I was doing something wrong. I eventually gave up on ARC and tried PostMan and set all the values the same and it worked on the server-side (I'm using node.js+hapi) where previously the server was returning 415 with little more info (there's an open issue in Hapi regarding this).

After seeing the requests at the server when using PostMan and considering the UI feedback ARC regarding multi-part (implying it would overwrite any included content-type headers), I've concluded that it's supposed to overwrite/include the content-type header AND provided the boundary, but is not and so my requests were failing.

I've also looked at closed and open issues for ARC ( https://github.com/jarrodek/ChromeRestClient/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20multipart ) and it looks a lot like there are known issues with multi-part uploads from the client so I'd suggest you not spend too much more time with ARC until you've tried another client to eliminate ARC as the source of your issues.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set proper Content-Type header

`Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7d01ecf406a6`

Server needs to know what to look for in the request body. In case of multipart/form-data you need to pass the boundary you have used in the Content-Type header.

Comment: Your answer is not wrong in general, but see mine and the specifics of the question as they relate to the Advanced Rest Client and file uploading and you'll see that your answer is not appropriate for this question.

Comment: I don't agree. The question is about the message structure. Structure in the question is ok but it missing proper content type header. So it is the answer to the question.